# FPS drop down when enabling iAd

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

My spriteKit game work fine at 60fps but when enabling iAd it drops to 15, sometimes 10 or even lower.. and it's a pain, when I die sometimes it takes a while to reset the scene. 
I've ran the analyzer on x-code 6 and I get a lot of low importance warnings:
[image: warnings]

but also this message:[image]

I've added iAd in the implementation of my `viewController.m` file like this:

```
@implementation XYZViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //AUDIO BACKground
    NSError *error;
    NSURL * backgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"spaceprueba160kbps" withExtension:@"mp3"];
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.backgroundMusicPlayer play];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;


    //iAd

    ADBannerView* adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
//    adView.delegate = self;
    [adView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)]; // set to your screen dimensions
    [adView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:adView];
//    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;



    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [XYZWorld1 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;



    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

I know I should un-comment that line -> `//    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;`
but it work fine like this and if I un-comment this line of code, I get a screen without iAdd and with my main camera looking a bit upper than the main screen. 
My game don't run in this file but in an instance of `SKScene`.

So my question is if anybody know how I can get back my 60 fps while keeping iAd on my screen.. ?

Comment: several people have seen the same issue - it may be an ios-beta specific thing. I suggest waiting for next betas or ios 8 final release and test again.

Comment: I were developing with x-code 6, but I switched back to x-code 5 and I'm under iOs 7.0.4

Comment: Is this on a real device because the simulator is not very good with displaying correct fps

Comment: Yes, this is on a real device. An iphone 4

Comment: I'm getting the same issue - on Xcode 6 (not beta) and using swift.  frame rate without iAds is around 60 but sometimes when an Ad banner animates it drops to about 40, especially after resuming the scene having clicked and closed an ad.  This is on an iPod touch and an iPhone 5s.